# Use multiple functions in MySQLdb (python)

Tags: python, mysql-python

this code below runs just fine, but i want to separate this code into function (this is my first time using MySQLdb) ,

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user_name","pass","db_name" )

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT activity_log.datetime FROM activity_log"
cursor.execute(sql)
date_data = cursor.fetchall()
for content in date_data:
    print content   

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Question: how could I create one database connection and use it to multiple functions, this is what i've wrote so far (doesn't work):

```
import MySQLdb

class DB():
    def __init__(self): 
        db = MySQLdb.connect("locahost", "user_name", "pass", "db_name")
        self.cur = db.cursor()

    def time_statistic(self):
        sql = "SELECT activity_log.datetime FROM activity_log"
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        self.date_data = self.cursor.fetchone()
        for content in self.date_data:
            print content 

    def test1(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = DB.connect("db_name" )
    db.time_statistic(self)
    db.test1(self)
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments to **init** to make sure that the class connects to the right DB.

```
import MySQLdb

class DB():
    def __init__(self, server, user, password, db_name): 
        db = MySQLdb.connect(server, user, password, db_name)
        self.cur = db.cursor()

    def time_statistic(self):
        sql = "SELECT activity_log.datetime FROM activity_log"
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        self.date_data = self.cursor.fetchone()
        for content in self.date_data:
            print content 

    def test1(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    db = DB(<server>, <user>, <password>, <db_name>)
    db.time_statistic()
    db.test1()
```

Replace the arguments in <> with actual values you need to connect to the db. You may also want to add some error handling in the above code.

Comment: Thank you Colwin for your answer, but the code still doesn't work, here the error message:

`File "read_MySql.py", line 4, in <module>
    class DB():
  File "read_MySql.py", line 7, in DB
    self.cur = db.cursor()
NameError: name 'db' is not defined`.

What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is this line in your init? db = MySQLdb.connect(server, user, password, db_name)

Comment: yes, it is -->`db = MySQLdb.connect(server, user, password, db_name)`

Comment: Can you add the entire traceback to your question?

Comment: My bad. I didn't check the indentation, used 'space' for `self.cur = db.cursor()`, but used 'tab' for the rest. Your code runs just fine. Thank you so much. You just made my day..:)

Comment: Can I ask one more question?
when i use `self.cur.fetchone()` the result is `2016-09-08 17:39:32` (show only one record) but `self.cur.fetchall()` , the result is `(datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 7, 27, 20),)` . Happen to all column, why used `self.cur.fetchall()` change the format of the records?

Comment: I think the result from fetchone should be a date time too. Can you do print(type(self.cur.fetchone())

Comment: `print type(self.cur.fetchone())` --> `<type 'NoneType'>`, but `print type(self.cur.fetchall())` --> `<type 'tuple'>`